# Why is cout outputting outputting backslashes and digits when I use it again?

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code (something I threw together trying to isolate a weird error in a chess program I'm trying to write):

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>

class piece{
public:
 piece() : COLOUR('C'){}
 const char COLOUR;
};

std::vector<piece*> makeEmptyLine(){
 std::vector<piece*> emptyLine;
 piece null;
 emptyLine.push_back(&null);
 return emptyLine;
}

int main(){
 std::vector<piece*> emptyLine = makeEmptyLine();
 std::cout << (*emptyLine[0]).COLOUR;
 std::cout << (*emptyLine[0]).COLOUR;
 std::cout << (*emptyLine[0]).COLOUR;
 return 0;
}
```

And the output is `C\367\367`

The first `std::cout << (*emptyLine[0]).COLOUR;` always prints "C" (the expected result). But when it's used again, it outputs that backslash and three digits which change depending on how many times I use cout in the program.

Answer (score 1):

You have an undefined behaviour because you use the address of a local variable `null` which is destroyed once your function `makeEmptyLine()` returns.

Does your compiler complain when you try to compile it with the highest warning level?